# overlapping labels issue in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

i have text values in my ggplot that are overlapping a line. i want to add a background to the text so that it doesnt look to messy when overlapping.

this is the code I'm currently using

```
plot <- ggplot2::ggplot(data_sample1, aes(x = `Player Name`, y = Value, fill = Label)) +
  ggplot2::geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge", width = 0.3) +
  ggplot2::scale_fill_manual(values = c("Left" = "royalblue1", "Right" = "royalblue4")) +
  ggplot2::labs(title = data_sample1$Title,x = "",y = "") +
  ggplot2::geom_hline(yintercept = 25, color = "gold") +
  ggplot2::geom_text(aes(label = round(Value)),
                     position = position_dodge(width = 0.3),
                     vjust = -0.4, fontface = "bold", 
                     size = 3.5, hjust = 0.5) +
  ggplot2::theme_minimal() +
  ggplot2::theme(legend.position = "top",
                 legend.title = element_blank(),
                 legend.key.size = unit(10, 'pt'),
                 plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, face = "bold", size = 20),
                 panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
                 panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
                 axis.ticks = element_blank(),
                 axis.text.y = element_blank(),
                 axis.text.x = element_text(face = "bold",size = 10))
  plot
```

[the output graph for the above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bqtc.png)

ive tried using ***geom_label()*** by replacing the ***geom_text()*** code with this

```
ggplot2::geom_label(aes(label = round(Value)),
                      vjust = -0.2,fontface = "bold", position = position_dodge(width = 0.9),
                      fill = "white", color = "black", size = 4, label.padding = unit(0.1, "lines"))
```

however it seems like the position_dodge code isnt working and i end up getting this.

[image]

any ideas?

Comment: Try `geom_label(aes(..., group = Label), ...)`. As you are using `fill="white"` you have dropped the implicit grouping. As a result `position_dodge` will not work.

Comment: ahhh yeah i added ```group = Label``` and ```position_dodge``` worked. you know how i can get rid of the black border though?

Comment: Try `geom_label(aes( ...), ..., label.size = 0)`.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that using `fill="white"` you have dropped the implicit default grouping by `fill=Label`. For that reason `position_dodge` will have no effect. To fix that you have to explicitly set the grouping using `group=Label` in `geom_label`. And to remove the label outline you could use `label.size = 0`. Additionally, note that as a nice feature `geom_label` allows to add some padding via `label.padding`. Hence, no need to shift the labels using `vjust`.

```r
library(ggplot2)

data_sample1 <- data.frame(
  Label = c("Left", "Right"),
  Value = c(24, 20),
  `Player Name` = "AK",
  check.names = FALSE
)

ggplot(data_sample1, aes(x = `Player Name`, y = Value, fill = Label)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge", width = 0.3) +
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = c("Left" = "royalblue1", "Right" = "royalblue4")
  ) +
  labs(title = data_sample1$Title, x = "", y = "") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 25, color = "gold") +
  geom_label(aes(label = round(Value), group = Label),
    position = position_dodge(width = 0.3),
    vjust = 0, fontface = "bold",
    size = 3.5, hjust = 0.5,
    fill = "white", label.size = 0,
    label.padding = unit(2, "mm")
  ) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    legend.position = "top",
    legend.title = element_blank(),
    legend.key.size = unit(10, "pt"),
    plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, face = "bold", size = 20),
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks = element_blank(),
    axis.text.y = element_blank(),
    axis.text.x = element_text(face = "bold", size = 10)
  )
```

[image]